# Regex detecting boundaries such as comments on the line of source code

Tags: c++, regex

Is it possible to create a regex which would return match/no match for the following lines?

```
/*8th*/break;  match

break;/*8th*/ match 

/*8th*/ no match
/*8th no match
8th*/ no match  
// /* some_comment    no match  
// some_comment no match
some_comment*/ no match
some_comment // match
```

If yes, could you please supply me with this regex?

Basically what I'm trying to catch is if there is anything on the line apart from comment.

Comment: Similar question: [C# removing comments from a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399213/c-sharp-removing-comments-from-a-string)

Comment: is this a match: `/* asd /* abcd */ qwe `

Comment: @Amarghosh yes, this would be considered a match

Answer (score 0):

You can't "really" do this with a regex. You can get 80% of the cases, but it's a complex problem. For instance, if you have a quoted string " */ " - a regex is just going to see */ and think the comment is closing.

You might have some luck looking at how syntax highlighters do it. or, [check this burly AWK script out](http://amit.chakradeo.net/files/xscc.awk.txt).

Comment: isn't there an option to tell regex to match if "the thing" isn't surrounded by quotes (or any other character for that matter)?

Comment: The problem is comment in comments, you can only go as far as you write your regex. Catch up to 3 levels with regex, 4 levels in code -> problem. Same holds for capturing code in accolades etc. Regex is just not suitable for source code. Period.

Comment: @demorge C++ doesn't support nested comments, and the question is about C++.

Comment: @Archie Technically `/* aasd //asd */ is nested comment - so if this comes in a multiline comment...

Comment: A nested comment isn't always a nested comment.. A poorly constructed regex wouldn't really understand how to handle the following.. // All the good files live in "/home/*/users/*/"